# How to fix Instance member cannot be used on type segmentedControl

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, uisegmentedcontrol

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorder(){
        let backgroundImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.white.cgColor, andSize: self.bounds.size)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .highlighted, barMetrics: .default)

        let deviderImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.white.cgColor, andSize: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        self.setDividerImage(deviderImage, forLeftSegmentState: .selected, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 129/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)], for: .selected)
    }

    func addUnderlineForSelectedSegment(){
        removeBorder()
        let underlineWidth: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)
        let underlineHeight: CGFloat = 2.0
        let underlineXPosition = CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex * Int(underlineWidth))
        let underLineYPosition = self.bounds.size.height - 1.0
        let underlineFrame = CGRect(x: underlineXPosition, y: underLineYPosition, width: underlineWidth, height: underlineHeight)
        let underline = UIView(frame: underlineFrame)
        underline.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 129/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)
        underline.tag = 1
        self.addSubview(underline)
    }

    func changeUnderlinePosition(){
        guard let underline = self.viewWithTag(1) else {return}
        let underlineFinalXPosition = (self.bounds.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            underline.frame.origin.x = underlineFinalXPosition
        })
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    class func getColoredRectImageWith(color: CGColor, andSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        let graphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        graphicsContext?.setFillColor(color)
        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        graphicsContext?.fill(rectangle)
        let rectangleImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return rectangleImage!
    }
}
```

I then call the function in the `ViewDidLoad` by:

```
segmentedControl.changeUnderlinePosition()
```

I end up getting the following error message:

> Instance member 'changeUnderlinePosition' cannot be used on type
> 'segmentedControl'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image of what the error message is

[image]

Comment: Code looks fine to me. How you declared `segmentedControl`  object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a custom type named `segmentedControl` and calling the method on it. You need to remove or rename if there is such a declaration in your code. Better to rename it to `MyCustomSegmentedControl` from `segmentedControl`.

```
class segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl { ... } // rename or remove
```

You need to call the method on it's instance instead, like this:

```
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
segmentedControl.changeUnderlinePosition()
```

Comment: I tried adding the following code to my viewdidload although i got the same error message, I am somewhat new to swift could you walk me through it?

Comment: Did you remove the declaration that I've mentioned in my post?

Comment: No i added it cause I thought thats what you wanted me to do

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. You've to remove any custom class that is named the same as your property. And add the second declaration to your code.

Comment: Got it I no longer have the error message, the code isn't working though do you have any idea whats wrong with it? (its fine if not i just accepted your answer)

Comment: Good, so there is progress, you're in the right path. Check a few tutorials on UISegmentedControl, there are many. If you still can't figure it out post a new question here and leave the link in the comments and I'll to help you out.

Comment: I just posted a new question!